# Limit SQL query by repeated entries

Tags: mysql, sql

I think it's easier to understand what I want by an example:

records :

NAME    DATA

**AAAAA**   *share it*
**AAAAA**   *Astronomy*
**AAAAA**   *Math*
**BBBBB**   *share it*
**CCCCC**   *share it*
**CCCCC**   *Soccer*

I want to select the first two records (with ALL data).
(If the record has NAME repeated, get it and don't count as an record)
I want to get this:

**AAAAA**   *share it*
**AAAAA**   *Astronomy*
**AAAAA**   *Math*
**BBBBB**   *share it*

I don't know if it's easy to understand.

Comment: Your example is not very obvious.  Perhaps you should expand it so that a pattern emerges.  For ex., why is `BBBBB share it` included but `CCCCC share it` is not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a 
        INNER JOIN
        (
          SELECT DISTINCT Name
          FROM tableName
          ORDER BY Name 
          LIMIT 2
        ) b ON a.Name = b.Name
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/574db/2)

Comment: THank you!
Now, how do I do another inner join with another table (on name)?

Comment: @MaurícioGiordano [is this what you mean? (*click here*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ec31/1)

Comment: It was that.

Thank you again ;)